# Azure Portal metrics extraction for external use

Tags: json, azure, portal, dashing, azure-application-insights

Having scoured the internet for a viable solution I have come up empty handed. I have concluded however that there is **no current API for extracting the raw data** from the Azure Portal Application Insights and so wondered if anyone else out there has managed to achieve this?

My quandary is, **I am wanting to display some of the raw data on a dashing dashboard widget** based on some logic and without the basic url that gives me the JSON, I am at a loss.

Any help would be greatly received, even if it is a conclusive, it cannot be done.

Thanks in advance, Mark

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only method to extract raw data from Azure Application Insights is to export the blob files and extract it from them. There are discussions on Visual Studio [forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?category=visualstudio&forum=vsto%2Clightswitch%2Cvsta%2Cvstest%2Clsextensibility%2Cmsbuild%2Cvsx%2Cvsarch%2Cvssetup%2CTFService%2Cvsunittest%2Cvsdebug%2Cvsmantest%2Cvseditor%2CApplicationInsights%2Cvisualstudiogeneral&sort=relevancedesc&brandIgnore=True&searchTerm=application%20insights) where people are asking for something simpler to be implemented. Who knows, it may happen.